# How can I fetch branch names from the git branch -r output

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cut

When I do `git branch -r`, each line seems prefixed with the remote name.

```
$ git --no-pager branch -r

origin/feature/XXX-NNN
origin/feature/XXX-NNN
origin/feature/XXX-NNN

$
```

How can I fetch those `feature/.+` part using a command line?

So that I want to do something with,

```
feature/XXX-1
feature/XXX-243
```

Comment: You can let git do all the work: `git for-each-ref  --format='%(refname:lstrip=3)' --no-contains HEAD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `HEAD` line and the remote prefix as follows:

```
git branch -r | sed '/HEAD/d;s|^[^/]*/||'
```